Need screenshots of the Ubuntu installation process for a college project
I need screenshots from the Ubuntu installation process for a college project, but unfortunately I don't have access to a computer right now to perform the installation.
Could someone share some images or guide me on where I can find them? Specifically I need screenshots of steps like partition creation, user setup, and installation completion.

A gallery of .png screenshots of the complete Ubuntu 24.04 installation process is available at this GitHub page. Skip over the first four screenshots to get to the start of the Ubuntu installation process.
Ubuntu 24.04 is the latest long term support version of Ubuntu.
